# Writing/Reading string in Registry in C++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, registry

How to write/read a string in windows registry in C++ ?

I am able to write/read DWORD (number) in windows registry using the following code. But, unable to write/read a string value, as it gets stored as chinese like characters in the registry.

```
void SetVal(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpValue, DWORD data)
{
    LONG nError = RegSetValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&data, sizeof(DWORD));

    if (nError)
        cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not set registry value: " << (char*)lpValue << endl;
}

DWORD GetVal(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpValue)
{
    DWORD data;     DWORD size = sizeof(data);  DWORD type = REG_DWORD;
    LONG nError = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&data, &size);

    if (nError==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        data = 0; // The value will be created and set to data next time SetVal() is called.
    else if (nError)
        cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not get registry value " << (char*)lpValue << endl;

    return data;
}
```

Code used to write/read string value (Stored as chinese like characters in the registry):

```
void SetVal(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpValue, string data)
{
    LONG nError = RegSetValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)&data, sizeof(data));

    if (nError)
        cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not set registry value: " << (char*)lpValue << endl;
}

string GetVal(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpValue)
{
    string data;     DWORD size = sizeof(data);  DWORD type = REG_SZ;
    LONG nError = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&data, &size);

    if (nError==ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        data = "0"; // The value will be created and set to data next time SetVal() is called.
    else if (nError)
        cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not get registry value " << (char*)lpValue << endl;

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Could you to post a [MCVE].

Comment: `sizeof(DWORD)` when dealing with a null-terminated string is wrong.  It returns the size of a DWORD (pointer?), not the length of the string. Unless you're writing a very short string, the value is far too small. You're also not null terminating your string.

Comment: You posted the code for reading/writing DWORD values instead of your failing code reading/writing string values.

Comment: @MichaelWalz I have added the code in the description now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are naively casting `string` type variables to `LPBYTE`.

This is your code with corrections:

```
void SetVal(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpValue, string data)
{
  const char *x = data.c_str();
  LONG nError = RegSetValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)data.c_str(), data.size());

  if (nError)
    cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not set registry value: " << (char*)lpValue << endl;
}

string GetVal(HKEY hKey, LPCTSTR lpValue)
{
  string data; 
#define MAXLENGTH 100

  char buffer[100];
  DWORD size = sizeof(buffer);
  DWORD type = REG_SZ;

  LONG nError = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)buffer, &size);

  if (nError == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
  {
    data = "0"; // The value will be created and set to data next time SetVal() is called.
    return data;
  }
  else if (nError)
    cout << "Error: " << nError << " Could not get registry value " << (char*)lpValue << endl;

  data = buffer;
  return data;
}
```

There is still room for improvement, for example the maximum string length is limited to 100 and the error handling should be improved.

**Explanations:**

This is your code in `SetVal`

```
RegSetValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&data, sizeof(DWORD));
```

- you are naively casting `data` to `LPBYTE`.
- `sizeof(DWORD)` is wrong, because you need to provide the length of the string

This is your code in `GetVal`:

```
    string data;
    DWORD size = sizeof(data);
    DWORD type = REG_SZ;
    LONG nError = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, lpValue, NULL, &type, (LPBYTE)&data, &size);
```

- `sizeof(data)` when `data` is a `string` doesn't make any sense. It is not the length of the string, which at that moment is 0 anyway.
- you are again casting naively `string` to `LPBYTE` when calling `RegQueryValueEx`

Comment: Its still not working for me. Still getting a set of Chinese characters in the registry.